# Jetty: storing session data in couchbase server

Tags: jetty, couchbase

Short description

I am looking for session manager for Jetty server which can store data couchbase cluster. I want to have advantage of couchbase server that if one server goes down, application doesn't get affected.

Long description

Currently I am using couchbase cluster as session store for Jetty Server in the following way

1. Installed this library https://github.com/yyuu/jetty-nosql-memcached
2. Have a default bucket on Couchbase with no password. Which listens on 1111 port and communicated with memcached protocol.
3. Configured above library in jetty. So this Jetty session store talks memcached protocol to one of the node of couchbase cluster.

This setup works well but there are few limitations.

1. I can not use non-default bucket to store session.
2. I can not have bucket password.
3. If one server(which I have configured in jetty.xml) of cluster goes down, session will stop working.

I am more concerned about point 3. So is there any session manager which can fit into these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Couchbase with Couchbase Bucket you will have automatic partitioning and replication of the session, so when a node goes down the cluster will failover this node and your application you continue to work transparently.

The issue you are describing in 1 & 2 are not related to Couchbase but to the implementation fo the "jetty-nosql-memcached" project. May be you can contribute to this project and add port change and SASL support.

Comment: Yes I am completely aware that this issue is not related to couchbase. I was just asking if there is some project similar to "jetty-nosql-memcached". Manish contributed to the project. Here is his implementaion https://github.com/mm87642/jetty-nosql-memcached